# Make postgresql query planner use my partial gin tsv index

Tags: sql, postgresql

Anyone have tricks to get the planner to favor my partial gin tsv index?

Here's the schema I'm working with.

```
create table dude (
    id integer primary key,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    house_id integer,
    ...)

alter table dude
    add constraint dude_house_id_fkey
    foreign key (house_id) references house (id);

create index ix_dude_house_id on dude (house_id);

create index ix_dude_first_last_name_tsv on dude
    using gin (to_tsvector('my_tsconfig'::regconfig, (first_name::text || ' '::text) || last_name::text)
    where house_id is not null and first_name is not null and last_name is not null;
```

`dude` has about 400 mln records but some of them have null first_name, last_name or email_id.

So I'm trying to search using the tsv index with the query

```
select *
from dude
where
    to_tsquery('my_tsconfig'::regconfig, 'george & michael'::text)
        @@ (to_tsvector('my_tsconfig'::regconfig, (first_name::text || ' '::text) || last_name::text))
    and house_id is not null
    and first_name is not null
    and last_name is not null;
```

and the plan I'm getting is;

```
Index Scan using ix_person_house_id on dude (cost=0.45..46673651.54 rows=8 width=327)
   Index Cond: (house_id IS NOT NULL)
   Filter: ((first_name IS NOT NULL) AND (last_name IS NOT NULL) AND ('''george'' & ''michael'''::tsquery @@ to_tsvector('my_tsconfig'::regconfig, (((first_name)::text || ' '::text) || (last_name)::text))))
```

The planner is favoring the btree on house_id, leading to a really slow query. I Suspect the problem here is I'm not specifying the expression correctly, so the planner can't consider using the partial index.

I should add that I have analyzed the table and I got the exact same plan.

Comment: I ended up seeing this behavior happen a couple other times with other partial indexes. The only reliable fix was to kill off any long running backend processes who's start_time predated creation of the index. I don't know why it works.

Comment: Also should add that I was using postgres 9.5